# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Select Database Syntax Error

Tags: sql-server, database, management-studio-express

I'm trying to type out some code to return the name of the current database. Literally every place I've seen says that you can type out

`SELECT DATABASE()`

to return that information, but when I try to do it in SSMS I get a syntax error for the DATABASE() function. No idea why it isn't working.

Comment: SQL-Server != MySQL.

Comment: I think you need to try: `SELECT DB_NAME()`

Comment: That seems to have worked. Up till this point I've managed using basic MySQL info, but this seems to be one of the few places were SQL-Server and MySQL differ. Thanks